# how to merge an array of objects to an array of objects contain object an array

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

is there a way to "merge" an array of objects' values?

For example, I would like to take an array like this . . .

```
input = [{name: 'x', data: 2},{name: 'y', data: 5},{name: 'x', data: 4},{name: 'y', data: 3}];
```

. . . and transform it into this

```
output = [{name: 'x', data: [2,4]},{name: 'y', data: [5,3]}]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
    let input = [{name: 'x', data: 2},{name: 'y', data: 5},{name: 'x', data: 4},{name: 'y', data: 3}];
    let out = [...new Set(input.map(i => i.name))].map(i => {
        return {name: i, data: input.filter(j => j.name === i).reduce((a,b)=> [a.data].concat([b.data])) };
    });
    console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution:

```
const output = input.reduce((previous, next, currentIndex, array) => {
  const index = previous.findIndex((item) => item.name === next.name);
  if (index >= 0) {
    previous[index].data.push(next.data);
  } else {
    previous.push({ ...next, data: [next.data] });
  }
  return previous;
}, []);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can accomplish this by generating a new array. Simply iterate through the input array and start accumulating the `data` values of every unique `name` field into the new merged array.
The code would look something like this:

```js
function merge(input){
    let merged = [];
    for (let i=0; i<input.length;i++) {
        let found = merged.findIndex(e => e.name === input[i].name);
        if (found === -1) {
             merged.push({ name: input[i].name, data: [ input[i].data ] });
        } else {
             merged[found].data.push(input[i].data);
        }
    }
    return merged;
}
```

Comment: There is a syntax error, also this is nearly identical to the solution above you.  Why even post this.